# Checking to see if row data has changed

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

My Goal:
Is to move data from one table to another if the row has been updated or a new row has been Inserted.

I have a table I needs certain fields from. I need to know if the row has been updated or inserted.
The Source table does not have any Timestamp fields. I'm using MSSQL2008. The data is coming from a client and they are controlling the tables and replication.

I thought I had it figure out using the new **Merge** function for MSSQL 2008 but it updates all rows whether or not anything has changed. This is normally not a big problem but I have to add a timestamp fields. My modified time fields will be update whether or not the row has been updated.

So I need a way to complete my above goal. I'm not a great SQL expert so as you can see I'm struggling any help would be great.

```
USE NaylorAequor
DECLARE CurretDate GetDate();

MERGE Aequor_SLA_Ads AS Target

USING (select AWA.AdOrderID,emp.FirstName, emp.LastName,AWA.VendorID,AO.OrderDate,AO.SaleStatusID,A.AdColorId,AO.PublicationID,AWA.DateAssigned,AWA.DateAdCompleted 
from AdWorkAssignMent as AWA, Employee as emp, AdOrder AS AO,Ad as A
WHERE VendorId = 'Aequor' AND emp.EmployeeID = AWA.EmployeeID AND AWA.AdOrderId = AO.AdOrderID AND AO.AdId = A.AdId) AS Source

ON (Target.AdOrderID = Source.AdOrderID) 

WHEN MATCHED THEN
         UPDATE SET 
            Target.AdOrderID =Source.AdOrderID,
            Target.FirstName = Source.FirstName,
            Target.LastName =Source.LastName,
            Target.VendorID =Source.VendorID,
            Target.OrderDate =Source.OrderDate,
            Target.SaleStatusID =Source.SaleStatusID,
            Target.AdColorId =Source.AdColorId,
            Target.PublicationID =Source.PublicationID,
            Target.DateAssigned =Source.DateAssigned,
            Target.DateAdCompleted =Source.DateAdCompleted,
            Target.AequorModifiedDateTime = GetDate()


WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
      INSERT (AdOrderID,FirstName,LastName,VendorID,OrderDate,SaleStatusID,AdColorId,PublicationID,DateAssigned,DateAdCompleted,AequorDateTime,AequorModifiedDateTime)

     VALUES (Source.AdOrderID, Source.FirstName,Source.LastName,Source.VendorID, Source.OrderDate,Source.SaleStatusID,Source.AdColorId,
                Source.PublicationID,Source.DateAssigned,Source.DateAdCompleted,GetDate(),GetDate())

OUTPUT $action, Inserted.*, Deleted.*;
```

Comment: Also just to clarify a `timestamp` column has nothing to do with date or time, in case there is any confusion about that. Are you talking about a column with the `TIMESTAMP` data type (just an alias for `ROWVERSION`), or are you talking about a column that stores date/time information (and you are loosely referring to as a "timestamp")? I wish I could have been there when they proposed that name for a `ROWVERSION` column - easily the biggest naming blunder in the history of Microsoft; even worse than Bob and `DATETIME2`.

Comment: @Aaron: I could never upvote that comment enough.  Spectacular.

Comment: @jadarnel27 it really is unfortunate that so many versions later we're *still* correcting mistaken assumptions based on that horrible name. And even in Denali, the name in `sys.types` is *still* `timestamp`, and `rowversion` is nowhere to be seen... <facepalm>

Comment: Aaron, first thank you Your right:  I was loosely using the term TimeStamp which I see now was wrong. my idea was to check against this column. Sorry about the uses of bad term. I will try the below solution and get back to you. again thank you.

Comment: Mike: just so you know, I think @Aaron was critisizing Microsoft's awful naming conventions, not so much your use of them =)  It is rather confusing.

Comment: No need to apologize, it's certainly not your fault. Just wanted to make sure everyone was clear about what data type you're talking about, that's all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the restriction that you only want to update the data if some of the values are different. So you have to change that part of the query for something like this:

```
WHEN MATCHED AND (  Target.FirstName != Source.FirstName OR 
                    Target.LastName != Source.LastName OR
                    Target.VendorID != Source.VendorID OR
                    Target.OrderDate != Source.OrderDate OR
                    Target.SaleStatusID != Source.SaleStatusID OR
                    Target.AdColorId !=Source.AdColorId OR
                    Target.PublicationID !=Source.PublicationID OR
                    Target.DateAssigned !=Source.DateAssigned OR
                    Target.DateAdCompleted !=Source.DateAdCompleted)
THEN
         UPDATE SET 
            Target.AdOrderID =Source.AdOrderID,
            Target.FirstName = Source.FirstName,
            Target.LastName =Source.LastName,
            Target.VendorID =Source.VendorID,
            Target.OrderDate =Source.OrderDate,
            Target.SaleStatusID =Source.SaleStatusID,
            Target.AdColorId =Source.AdColorId,
            Target.PublicationID =Source.PublicationID,
            Target.DateAssigned =Source.DateAssigned,
            Target.DateAdCompleted =Source.DateAdCompleted,
            Target.AequorModifiedDateTime = GetDate()
```

In this case, the comparison is assuming that every field is not nullable, if that's not the case, you need to add that to the logic as well (an `ISNULL` or something like that)

Comment: Wonder whether `NOT EXISTS(SELECT Source.* INTERSECT SELECT Target.*)` will work in this context.

Comment: @Martin Smith - I have to say that I have never even wondered if that could work....I'm interested now

Comment: Just tested with a toy example and it seems to. Just remembered this article talking about [`IS DISTINCT FROM`](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx) in SQL Server.

Comment: @Martin Smith - Thanks for the clarification....if you post it as an answer, I will upvote it

Answer (score 18):

Just as an addon to Lamak's answer because these inequality comparisons can get a bit tedious particularly where the columns are nullable you might want to replace them with `NOT EXISTS(SELECT Source.* INTERSECT SELECT Target.*)`

Example usage below

```
declare @t1 table
(
id int,
col2 int NULL
)

declare @t2 table
(
id int,
col2 int NULL
)

INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES(1, NULL),(2,NULL)
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES(1, NULL),(2,NULL), (3,NULL)

MERGE @t1 AS Target
USING  @t2 AS Source
ON (Target.id = Source.id) 
WHEN MATCHED AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT Source.* INTERSECT SELECT Target.*) THEN
         UPDATE SET 
            Target.id =Source.id
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
      INSERT (id)
      VALUES (id)
OUTPUT $action, Inserted.*, Deleted.*;
```

Comment: Might be worth noting MERGE ... WITH(HOLDLOCK) ..... in case people come by and copy and paste