# Sql Server - How compare hash of two rows in merge

Tags: sql-server

I have several working tables that I am merging together into one final table that will be used for display. If the display table does not contain the primary key compiled from the working tables (hereafter called src)then I insert the row into display. This works fine, the next part is confusing to me.

If the primary key is already in display I only want to update the display row if the src row has the same primary key but at least one column is different from the display row. I'd like to implement this using the HASHBYTES() method using the MD5 algorithm.

From msdn, the syntax should look like this: `HASHBYTES('MD5', {@variable | 'string'})`

I want to be able to do something like this in my merge statement:

`WHEN MATCHED AND HASHBYTES('MD5', display) != HASHBYTES('MD5', src) THEN ...(stuff)`

How do I complete the HASHBYTES function?

Here is my current merge statement

```
MERGE dbo.DisplayCases AS display
USING (SELECT CaseId, Title, projects.ProjectName, categories.CategoryTitle, Root, milestones.MilestoneName,
        milestones.MilestoneDate, Priority, statuses.StatusTitle, EstimatedHours, ElapsedHours, personAssigned.Name as AssignedTo,
        personResolved.Name as ResolvedBy, cases.IsResolved, IsOpen, Opened, Resolved, Uri, ResolveUri,
        OutlineUri, SpecUri, ParentId, Backlog
        FROM fogbugz.Cases cases
        JOIN fogbugz.Projects projects ON cases.ProjectId = projects.ProjectId
        JOIN fogbugz.Categories categories ON cases.CategoryId = categories.CategoryId
        JOIN fogbugz.Milestones milestones ON cases.MilestoneId = milestones.MilestoneId
        JOIN fogbugz.Statuses statuses ON cases.Status = statuses.StatusId
        JOIN fogbugz.People personAssigned ON cases.AssignedTo = personAssigned.Id
        LEFT JOIN fogbugz.People personResolved ON cases.ResolvedBy = personResolved.Id
        ) as src
ON display.CaseId = src.CaseId
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(CaseId, CaseTitle, ProjectName, CategoryTitle, RootId, MilestoneName, MilestoneDate, Priority,
        StatusTitle, EstHrs, ElapsedHrs, AssignedTo, ResolvedBy, IsOpen, IsResolved, Opened, Resolved, Uri,
        ResolveUri, OutlineUri, Spec, ParentId, Backlog)
    VALUES(src.CaseId, src.Title, src.ProjectName, src.CategoryTitle, src.Root, src.MilestoneName,
        src.MilestoneDate, src.Priority, src.StatusTitle, src.EstimatedHours, src.ElapsedHours,
        src.AssignedTo, src.ResolvedBy, src.IsResolved, src.IsOpen, src.Opened, src.Resolved,
        src.Uri, src.ResolveUri, src.OutlineUri, src.SpecUri, src.ParentId, src.Backlog);
```

Comment: What's the reason for wanting to use `HASHBYTES`? You could do `WHEN MATCHED AND EXISTS(SELECT Source.* EXCEPT SELECT Target.*) THEN
 UPDATE ...`

Comment: @MartinSmith I wasn't familiar with EXISTS, but I'm not sure it's what I need. In my case there will frequently be rows that are exactly equal and I want to ignore those instead of updating if something in the row has changed. Also, when I use `EXISTS(SELECT src.* EXCEPT display.*)` it errors saying I need a boolean value

Comment: Yes that's what that will do. [Example syntax here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339905/checking-to-see-if-row-data-has-changed/7341058#7341058)

Comment: great, that worked - if you make as an answer then I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Martin Smith's comment...

You could do `WHEN MATCHED AND EXISTS(SELECT Source.* EXCEPT SELECT Target.*) THEN UPDATE ...`